# UserManager генерирует исключение ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, ninject, signalr

Создаю зависимость для класса PostHub(наследует Hub)

```
     GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(PostHub),
     () => new PostHub(
     HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(),
     new RepositoryManager(new DataDbContext())));
     app.MapSignalR();
```

После уже инициализирую

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;
    private readonly IRepositoryManager repositoryManager;

    public PostHub(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,IRepositoryManager repositoryManager)
    {
        this.repositoryManager = repositoryManager;
        this.UserManager = userManager;
    }
```

При использовании repositoryManager все происходит нормально, однако при вызове методов UserManager генерируется исключение: "ObjectDisposedException: Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен.". C чем это связано и как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Решение состоит в том, чтобы вручную создать экземпляр класса `ApplicationUserManager`

```
     this.UserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Почему не работает способом, который указан в вопросе?
- Предполагаю, что это связано с `HttpContext`, ведь обращение к классу хаб осуществляется с помощью иного протокола(к примеру, `WebSocket`)